# Tag Synonim / Tag Merge: [debug] --> [debugging]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just noticed this two tag ([debug](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug) - [debugging](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging))floating on the main site. Looking at the posted questions, I could not see any difference that would justificate different tags.

I suggest to either merge the two tags or create a synonim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I've merged debug into debugging.

Comment: Perfect. As always, I will report any other strange tags I may find in the same way.

Comment: Sounds good. :)